# Сгенерировать последовательность чисел от 000000 до 99999

Tags: c#, list, range

Есть метод `Enumerable.Range(0,n)` который генерирует последовательность чисел от 0 до n, однако хотелось бы узнать как генерировать такую последовательность чисел

```
000000
000001
000002
```

...

Comment: Так же, только добавить в формат ведущие нули. ToString("D6")

Comment: @AK это понятно. А как этот метод пихнуть в Enumaerable.Range?

Comment: Циклом For не так красиво это будет)

Comment: Enumerable.Range().Select(ToString)

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, n).Select(x => x.ToString("D6"))`

Answer (score 5):

Используя `Linq`:

```
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 99999).Select(n => n.ToString("D6"));
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/6HbTNz

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) маленький вопрос вдогонку. Допустим мне надо сделать .ToString("D7"). Число 7 хранится в переменной. Как правильно сконкатенировать их? Я пробую ToString("D"+7) но оно неверно генерит

Comment: @Radzhab Могли бы и не задавать [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693725/213987), он ведь действительно маленький.