# Динамический формат в ToString()

Tags: c#

Вдогонку к [предыдущему вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693702/213987).

Есть строка

```
var rez = Enumerable.Range(0, maxValue)
    .Select(n => n.ToString(string.Format("D{0}", maxValue)))
    .ToList();
```

Я изначально знаю значение числа `maxValue`, однако несовсем понятно как его передать в метод `ToString()`?

Я пробовал так тоже

```
ToString("D"+maxValue)
```

По ходу неправильно я их конкатенирую.

Comment: Что у вас должно быть на входе и что на выходе?

Answer (score 2):

> маленький вопрос вдогонку. Допустим мне надо сделать .ToString("D7").
>   Число 7 хранится в переменной. Как правильно сконкатенировать их? Я
>   пробую ToString("D"+7) но оно неверно генерит

Точно также:

```
var size = 6;
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 99999).Select(n => n.ToString($"D{size}"));
```

Или, если версия до 7.0 то по-старинке:

```
var size = 6;
var format = string.Format("D{0}", size);
var range = Enumerable.Range(0, 99999).Select(n => n.ToString(format));
```